# Match a type to a subtype without keeping extra properties

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have two types A, B

I would like to populate the values for all of the fields that match between A and B but any extra fields should not be included in the result.

How do I do this?

To make this clearer

```
let a : A = { a : 'b' , b : 'c' }
let b : B = { a : 'j' }

let c : A intersect B = { a : 'j' } (take only B's values)
```

Comment: Can you post some code so that it easier to understand what you're asking?

Comment: Please give a specific example of A and B along with your desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean `populate`.

Here you have an example:

```js
type A = {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    age: number
}

type B = {
    name: string;
    surname: string;
    status: boolean;
}

type CommonFields = A | B;

type Test = keyof CommonFields
```

Union of types allows you to deal only with common properties.

**UPDATE**
Let me know if it works for you

```js
type A = { a: string, b: string }
type B = { a: string }

type Uncommon<T, U> = {
    [Prop in keyof (T & U)]: Prop extends keyof T ? Prop extends keyof U ? never : Prop : Prop
}[keyof (T & U)]

type PickUncommon<T, U> = Pick<T & U, Uncommon<T, U>>

// {
//     b: string;
// }
type Result = PickUncommon<A, B>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKBnYAnAlgHYDmANFAEaY4ElQC%20AsAFCiRQBCCya1eRxBixZtoAVUIBjAPYBbWdMIAeACrkxAPm5IWUPVADaABVzSwUIlADWEENIBmUABQqoAMihiAlAF1MJsygIAA9gCEIAEyxrWwcoVwB%20KADzELDI6Js7RzEoJMIIADcIXCh-U3NysxZ6Ayy4l3dPX2FWcGgjfEkrCRl5RVV1LURO7tUmsXUpOQVlNU8NDVaAemXkFlX9PSpsfhIAbg21pjb2ACUILABXABtgblGe6f7lGHIODSA)

Comment: If by `populate` they mean `assign to a variable of a type` then they would probably want a type `intersection` instead of a `union`. But a basic intersection wouldn't work either because it doesn't check for excess properties in object literal assignment.

Comment: Hi, thank but how would you use type Test to get the values from a particular instance? ( edited my question for clarity)